# Converting VOB to mp4 (h264) using ffmpeg results in a different length (bya few frames)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a VOB file that I want to convert to h264 using x264. I used:

```
ffmpeg -i 01.VOB -f mp4  -c:v libx264  -profile:v baseline -crf 17  -c:a toolame -vbr 3  prehratelne.mp4
```

which gave me this:

```
Input #0, mpeg, from '01.VOB':
  Duration: 01:22:01.44, start: 0.360000, bitrate: 6395 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7700 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x1567ae0] using SAR=64/45
[libx264 @ 0x1567ae0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x1567ae0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x1567ae0] 264 - core 142 r2495 6a301b6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=17.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'a.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  107 fps=0.0 q=22.0 size=     379kB time=00:00:03.91 bitrate= 794.0kbits/frame=  178 fps=178 q=22.0 size=     773kB time=00:00:06.64 bitrate= 952.7kbits/frame=  247 fps=164 q=22.0 size=    1131kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate= 979.9kbits/frame=  289 fps=139 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1620kB time=00:00:11.56 bitrate=1148.3kbits/s    
video:1569kB audio:45kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.425711%
```

However, the resulting files have a difference in length and start of about 80 miliseconds:

```
ffmpeg -i *.VOB 2>&1 | grep Duration
  Duration: 01:22:01.44, start: 0.360000, bitrate: 6395 kb/s
ffmpeg -i prehratelne.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration
  Duration: 01:22:01.53, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 4737 kb/s
```

Why is that, can it be somehow fixed? Ideally, I would have files that correspond frame by frame.

Comment: I can't tell you what's happening, but I can say that you're never going to get files that match "frame by frame" because neither codec stores individual frames. Instead they store interframe information with a complete keyframe every so often. The exact number and spacing of these will differ between codecs and will vary with the parameters you choose.

Comment: Great answer provided by @avnr: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/15591/10976